# Doing jquery things angular way

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a sidenavigation bar for my dashboard and in the process of building it, found a good tutorial which has built something similar. I'm planning to use this as a base work and will customise it afterwards. In the tutorial, the dynamic things have been handled using Jquery. Since I'm using Angularjs for my development, I want to do it Angular way. Can anyone please explain me how can I accomplish it.

Following is the [link](http://seegatesite.com/create-simple-cool-sidebar-menu-with-bootstrap-3/) to tutorial.

**Code snippets:**

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
     $("#menu-toggle-2").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled-2");
        $('#menu ul').hide();
    });

     function initMenu() {
      $('#menu ul').hide();
      $('#menu ul').children('.current').parent().show();
      //$('#menu ul:first').show();
      $('#menu li a').click(
        function() {
          var checkElement = $(this).next();
          if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            return false;
            }
          if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $('#menu ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
            checkElement.slideDown('normal');
            return false;
            }
          }
        );
      }
    $(document).ready(function() {initMenu();});
```

How can I convert it to do line Angular way ?

Thanks

Comment: There is too much to explain about doing it the angular way. Try narrowing your request to something more specific.

Comment: Did you find the answer ? if you found the answer and my answer helped you ? can you vote me up since the guy vote me down for answering your anti pattern question ? regards ... BigDong

Answer (score -1):

Replace this bind event with a View/Controller mapping

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

In the view

```
<div id="menu-toggle" ng-click="toggleClass"></div>
```

Then in your angular controller

```
$scope.toggleClass = function(){
    angular.element('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled')
};
```

You can do the same for this one

```
 $("#menu-toggle-2").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled-2");
    $('#menu ul').hide();
});
```

**initMenu** can be triggered in your main controller, just replace the `$` with `angular.element`

If there are no old browser compatibility requirement, you should start using CSS3 class for transition instead of JS due to css perf vs js perf

```
function initMenu() {
  angular.element('#menu ul').hide(); 
  angular.element('#menu ul').children('.current').parent().show();
}

initMenu();
```

For the `$('#menu li a').click()` event, same, use the View/Controller mapping

Comment: Doing DOM manipulation within a controller in an anti-pattern.

Comment: True, did you vote down because of that ?  He should not use jQuery event so I think this code will fit for his needs !